# Error color when running on the android virtual machine

Tags: c++, android-studio, cocos2d-x

I use linux mint 19.3 and install cocos2d-x 4.0 to build the project to android in AndroidStudio all succeeded and I run the project on the android virtual machine but I get a monitor far different from running on linux. help me please.

[image]

Comment: Check that you use correct byte order in RGBA pixel. It is different for different OS.

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: There is a bug in your code, we can't fix it without a [mre]